# How to use linq query to multiple filter

Tags: c#, linq

In my front end have multiple filter criteria. such as

- Start date
- End date
- Place - this is multi select drop down
- Organizer - this is also multi select drop down

I have a table called `Meeting` and its data something like this.

```
+------------+--------+-----------+
| date       | place  | organizer |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 12/07/2020 | USA    | ALAN      |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 12/07/2020 | CANADA | PAUL      |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 12/07/2020 | USA    | ALAN      |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 12/07/2020 | USA    | JHONE     |
+------------+--------+-----------+
| 12/08/2020 | AUS    | PAUL      |
+------------+--------+-----------+
```

My question is, how can I write `linq` query to get following details,

- Start date = 12/07/2020
- End date = 14/07/2020
- Place - `USA, CANADA` (this can be multiple values from multi selector)
- Organizer - `ALAN, PAUL` (this can be multiple values from multi selector)

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 3):

```
Where(x => x.StartDate > filter.StartDate &&
        x.EndDate > filter.EndDate &&
        filter.Places.Contains(x.Place) &&
        filter.Organizers.Contains(x.Organizer))
```

Comment: `filter` means?

Comment: filter means your data for filtering, you can use only array without filter as in next answer.

Answer (score 3):

For the multiple items, you should check that the db item's value is in that array.
In this case the placesArray and organizerArray are the multi-selected values as a non-null collection.

```
.Where(dbItem => 
    dbItem.startDate >= startDate &&
    dbItem.endDate <= endDate &&
    placesArray.Contains(dbItem.place) &&
    organizerArray.Contains(dbItem.organizer)
)
```

Comment: here`placesArray` and `organizerArray` is my multi selector selected id's array? is it

Comment: yes you are correct. i updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found a solution for you. Here is my code given below. Please try it and let me know it works or not.

```
//Table Equivalent Class
public class Meeting
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string place { get; set; }
    public string organizer { get; set; }
}
void SearchMeeting()
{
        //Loading table information into List
        List<Meeting> Meeting = new List<Meeting>();
        Meeting.Add(new Meeting() { date = new DateTime(2020, 7, 12), place = "USA", organizer = "ALAN" });
        Meeting.Add(new Meeting() { date = new DateTime(2020, 7, 12), place = "CANADA", organizer = "PAUL" });
        Meeting.Add(new Meeting() { date = new DateTime(2020, 7, 12), place = "USA", organizer = "ALAN" });
        Meeting.Add(new Meeting() { date = new DateTime(2020, 7, 12), place = "USA", organizer = "JHONE" });
        Meeting.Add(new Meeting() { date = new DateTime(2020, 8, 12), place = "AUS", organizer = "PAUL" });

        Meeting.Add(new Meeting() { date = DateTime.Now, place = "A", organizer = "A1" });
        Meeting.Add(new Meeting() { date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), place = "B", organizer = "B1" });
        Meeting.Add(new Meeting() { date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), place = "C", organizer = "C1" });
        Meeting.Add(new Meeting() { date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-5), place = "V", organizer = "V1" });

        //Search Parameters
        List<string> selectedPlaced = new List<string>();
        selectedPlaced.Add("USA");
        selectedPlaced.Add("CANADA");
        List<string> selectedOrganizer = new List<string>();
        selectedOrganizer.Add("ALAN");
        selectedOrganizer.Add("PAUL");

        DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2020, 7, 12);
        DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2020, 7, 14);

        //Desire Linq
        var temp = from s in Meeting
                    where s.date >= startDate && s.date <= endDate && selectedPlaced.Contains(s.place) && selectedOrganizer.Contains(s.organizer)
                    select s;

        //Equivalent Desire Lambda Expression
        var temp2 =Meeting.Where(s=>s.date >= startDate && s.date <= endDate && selectedPlaced.Contains(s.place) && selectedOrganizer.Contains(s.organizer));
}
```

I have tried to create almost same class of that table and "Meeting" List Contains the exact rows as show in the example. "selectedPlaced" and "selectedOrganizer" are muti selected search parameters. Finally, I wrote both the LINQ and Lambda expression code for you.